# Why does IIS sometimes displaying the aspx source code for an error page?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I have an asp.net web forms website hosting on IIS. Everything works as expected except for error pages. I have custom error pages setup as follows in the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="error.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="error.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="error.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="error.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

If I visit mysite.com/x.aspx (x.aspx does not exist), it properly displays the error page. However, if I visit mysite.com/x (x does not exist), the aspx source code is displayed in the browser (starting with "<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile...").

Any ideas as to why this might be happening and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net is not receiving those "extension-less" requests, instead they are getting processed by the static file handler.

Basically you need to install URLReWrite module and rewrite/redirect the extension-less requests to your error.aspx page yourself. Theres various [examples on SO for handling extensionless URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net%20extensionless%20url)

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code in your web.conifg file:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="error.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="error.aspx"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Make sure  Error Pages in IIS Manager -> Feature Delegation is set to Read/Write.